# Error: "zsh: no matches found: apache-beam[gcp]" while installing Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, data-pipeline

I am working on a project and trying to install Apache Beam from the terminal using this command: pip3 install apache-beam[gcp] however I get this error: zsh: no matches found: apache-beam[gcp]

I created a virtual env using these commands:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs quotes per eg https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/installing-beam-sdk#python

```
pip install 'apache-beam[gcp]'
```

or

```
pip3 install 'apache-beam[gcp]'
```

Comment: or alternatively escape the square brackets - `pip install apache-beam\[gcp\]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `requirements.txt` file containing your `Python` packages to be not dependent on your `bash` type, then install the packages from this file on your virtual env.

To correctly manage the `Python` versions on your machine, you can install the [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) tool.

**Go to the root folder of your project and create a virtual env :**

```bash
python3 -m venv <virtual-environment-name>

python3 -m venv my-env
```

`my-env` is the name of the virtual env.

**Activate this venv :**

```bash
source my-env/bin/activate
```

**At the root of your project, create a file called `requirements.txt` :**

```
apache-beam[gcp]==2.46.0
```

**Run the following command :**

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```